# fatal error: math/Vector3.hh: No such file or directory

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to use atlas.cc, so follow the tutorial, but the system of gazebo update from 1.3 to 1.4, and then appear this error: fatal error: common/CommonTypes.hh: No such file or directory, so I modify the #include "common/CommonTypes.hh" to #include "gazebo-1.4/gazebo/common/CommonTypes.hh", and make it, then appear: fatal error: math/Vector3.hh: No such file or directory
how to solve it?
thanks a lot
best
guangda

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1815/fatal-error:-math/vector3.hh:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [lugd1229](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/79/lugd1229/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 75 on 2013-03-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2013-03-14**:
Could you edit the question and add the link for the tutorial you are following? Thanks

**Comment by [lugd1229](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/79/lugd1229/) on 2013-03-14**:
and appear this error:  osrf_msgs/JointCommands.h: No such file or directory, I think other files cannot be found,  like#include <atlas_msgs/ForceTorqueSensors.h>//
//#include <atlas_msgs/ControllerStatistics.h>
//#include <sensor_msgs/JointState.h> how to solve it ,thank you

**Comment by [lugd1229](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/79/lugd1229/) on 2013-03-14**:
I follow this tutorial :http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/UserGuide and http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.4/ros_enabled_model_plugin,  I hope I can use a plugin like atlas to control 7 joints and can measure all the force and torque of these joints, so I copy atlasplugin.cc and atlasplugin.hh, and want to modify them to meet my need, but I meet lot of question,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Seems like the problem could be with the location of gazebo header files.

If they were installed from sources using no cmake variable to control destination, they are probably in */usr/local/include*. */usr/local* should be supplied as include path to the compiler.

You could try several solutions or workarounds, always keep the `<common/CommonTypes.hh>` this way, do not modify it:

1. Install gazebo from ubuntu packages. Problem locating `<common/CommonTypes.hh`> should not appear.
2. Install gazebo from sources using cmake .. `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr`
3. Modify the tutorial cmake to include /usr/local

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2013-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1